# getting null for PythonInterpreter.get() when using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython, pythoninterpreter

I'm using Jython to try to call a certain method in my Python file.
I'm getting error message like this

```
[ERROR]  - Ambiguous method overloading for methodorg.python.util.PythonInterpreter#exec.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String]
[class org.python.core.PyObject]
```

Here's my Java code

```
static def visitPage(){
    PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
    sys.path.append(new PyString(*The path to certain package*));
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(null, sys);
    interpreter.execfile(*Here's the path to the python file*);

    PyObject waitPage = interpreter.get("wait");
    println waitPage.toString();
    interpreter.exec(waitPage);
}
```

The print result gives me null. So I think my problem is not able to get the method. Here's my Python code. I'm getting access to a method that is inherited by LoginPage class, from Page Object class.

```
class LoginPage(PageObject):
```

So I'm wondering if there is another way I can use Jython's Python Interpreter?

Comment: The first part of your question seems irrelevant to me.  I think you are really asking how to use Jython to call a Python method from Java.  If I am right, you should recast your question accordingly, and expand upon the Python code example to show the method, and not just the first line of the class delcaration.

Comment: Hi, it turned out that because of the structure of the original python code, it would be not ideal to use Jython. It will even be simpler to rewrite in Java, so we switched to another approach. Thanks anyway